# Calling modal operator from prop update function ---> wrong context (how to change context for modal operator)

Tags: python, properties, operator, error

I have a modal operator to get the face index under mouse position from raycast (close to the "operator_modal_view3d_raycast.py" template).

```
class VaSelect(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.add_va"
    bl_label = "add va"

    def modal(self, context, event):

        if bpy.context.scene.VA_Mode != "VaEditMode":
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        else:
            get_face_index(context, event)
            return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
```

**If i use a panel button to start it, it works fine and as intended.**

When i try to invoke it from an EnumProperty update function:

```
def va_mode_update(self, context):
    if bpy.context.scene.VA_Mode == 'VaEditMode':
        bpy.ops.wm.add_va('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

i get this error message:

```
[...]
File "C:\Program Files\Blender3D\2.79\scripts\modules\bpy_extras\view3d_utils.py", line 46, in region_2d_to_vector_3d
    viewinv = rv3d.view_matrix.inverted()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'view_matrix'
```

Edit: What i found out so far:
When i start from Panel Button bpy.context.region.type is WINDOW but when i start from update function, it is TOOLS. So, as long as i cannot change the context while modal is running it will not work, right? (And.. i cannot.. or can i?)

Edit2:
it seems to be possible:
https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.ops.html#execution-context

Edit3:
I used override method (in the raycast_function) to feed the raycast with the correct context:

```
update function
    override = {'region': "", 'rv3d': ""}
    for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
        screen = window.screen

        for area in screen.areas:
            if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                for region in area.regions:
                    if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                        override['region'] = region
                for rv3d in area.spaces:
                    if hasattr(rv3d, 'region_3d'):
                        override['rv3d'] = rv3d.region_3d

    # get the context arguments
    scene = bpy.context.scene
    region = override['region']
    rv3d = override['rv3d']
    coord = event.mouse_region_x, event.mouse_region_y
```

It works now... somehow. Unfortunately the mouse cursor is offset. -.-

edit4:

When i use override as intended (at least i think i do, most likely i do something wrong, i am a very beginner :/):

```
class VaHighlight(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.add_va"
    bl_label = "Add Va"

    #override context to be able to call the operator from a enum property update function
    override = bpy.context.copy()
    for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
        screen = window.screen

        for area in screen.areas:
            if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                for region in area.regions:
                    if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                        override['region'] = region

    def modal(self, override, event):

        if bpy.context.scene.VA_Mode != "VaEditMode":
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        else:              
            get_face_index(override, event)
            return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = bpy.context.window_manager
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

def get_face_index(context, event):

    # get the context arguments
    scene = context.scene
    region = context.region
    [...]
```

the function does still not use the overwritten context but bpy.context (that is why i did it the way i did and move it into the function. This way it worked... except the offset. But that should be the same even if i get the override stuff working as intended.

Sure there is no attribute rv3d in bpy.context, but here i just pass the right context to the variable "rv3d" using the key rv3d of the dic named override ...)

area.regions[-1] does work but the region is not the (main) problem, it is rv3d = context.region_data. Took me beginner a good part of the day to find the "solution" i have atm.

Comment: You override context and pass that dictionary to an operator.  There is no context attribute rv3d. This is why when you have an operator method like `def modal(self, context, event):`  in its code, use `area = context.area`  and **NOT** `area = bpy.context.area`  This way if we override context `override["area"] = some_3d_view_area` and pass it to the op `bpy.ops.some.operator(override)` it will use the overridden context elements.

Comment: If the enum is in the TOOLS region, the hassle is prob in the operator code that uses `region = context.region`,   get  the WINDOW region  from the `context.area` instead by looking at its type like above (or its generally `area.regions[-1]` in my experience).  There should IMO be no need to override context in this case.

Comment: @batFINGER I answered as edit of my question, it is too long for comment.

Comment: Ok . `area = context.area` ... `region = area.regions[-1]` .... `r3dv = area.spaces.active.region_3d`  You are not using override as intended.  You make a dictionary with context members and pass it as first argument to the operator. Use the context argument in operator methods.  Dont use `bpy.context` or your overriden context members wont work.  Eg you would have an `override["region_data"]` member not a r3vd.  Check out `override = context.copy()` in the console.

Comment: @batFINGER That works to replace the whole override stuff, thx :) (i feel dumb that it took me so long to find a verbose ugly solution when it is so easy and short *sigh*). Sadly the problem with the offset remains. No cursor offset when using a panel button, but (quite large) cursor offset when using the enum prop update function.

Comment: Add a link to your code and will have a look.

Comment: Start by removing `bpy.context` and use the context passed, which will be the override you are sending to it. Same with your update function, use the context parameter. And in edit four - the class variable override isn't going to help, move that into the modal or it's own method.

Comment: @batFINGER can i send you the .blend privat somehow? (there s no bpy.context in the raycast function)

Comment: @batFINGER https://pastebin.com/mAXukMiQ thx for your effort. P.S.: To see the effect of highligting move thhe mouse over the object. To see it with the offset you need to be around 200px left of the object.

Comment: Try `bpy.ops.wm.add_voxel('INVOKE_REGION_WIN')` in your update method.

Comment: @batFINGER :D That works. Thank you very much :)